# Redirecting to port 3000 if accessed by a certain domain in IIS

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, iis-7, httpd.conf

I'm running IIS on port 80 & Apache on port 3000. How can I have IIS to redirect requests with a certain domain name to the Apache on 3000?

For example, requests to "x.com" would eventually lead the user to 1.2.3.4:80, while requests to "y.com" would bring them to 1.2.3.4:3000.

Its all setup on windows server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS supports redirection to an exact URL, as well as a relative url that appends the querystring.  See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true for IIS6 and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969(v=ws.10).aspx for IIS7.

Note: for IIS7, redirection is an optional feature, and may need to be installed separately.